# Perform a vibration on Apple Watch when a Picker scroll over the Limit

Tags: xcode, uipickerview, apple-watch, taptic-engine

I know that `WKInterfaceDevice.currentDevice().playHaptic(.Click)` perform a vibration from Apple Watch's Taptic engine.

Now I want to perform a click when a picker reach the limit and user keep scrolling.

I mean: I have a 0...99 picker, I want that Apple Watch click when the reach 0 or 99 and keep scrolling. 
If picker scroll between 0 and 99 I can't write

```
    if value > 99 {
        WKInterfaceDevice.currentDevice().playHaptic(.Click)
    }
```

because picker will never goes over 99, so how can I do that?